# Restoring a BAK to Multiple Target Databases In Parallel

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, parallel-processing

I have a `BAK` database backup and I'm attempting to restore it to N databases (around 20-30).

The `BAK` is in Azure File Storage.

I've attempted to script this with a powershell workflow (using AzCopy to copy from File Storage to the destination servers in parallel), but this approach simply does not work as the host machine's CPU and disk IO become a bottleneck almost instantly.

How can I go about restoring a BAK to N VMs in an automated and parallelized fashion?

FYI - my code for the parallel AZCopy command is something like this (it works, it's just a terrible approach):

```
foreach -parallel ($dir in $destinations)
{
    InlineScript{
       &"$Using:AzCopyPath" /Source:"$Using:sourceDirectory" /Dest:$Using:dir /SourceKey:$Using:sourceKey /Pattern:"$Using:sourcePattern" /Z:$journalPath
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is the target (i.e. where you're doing the restore) local or also in Azure? Can you queue the requests up into something like Service Broker and have it process a couple at a time until it's done?

Comment: @BenThul all targets are Azure VMs, yes.  A couple at a time would take days - I need all done in parallel :(

Comment: Then it sounds like you need a bigger box. Right now, you're kicking off a large number of file copies and running into limitations. As it's Azure, you could dynamically scale up the machine to accommodate for this and then scale it back when you're done.

Comment: Maybe a better way would be to have a job that starts a new job on the target vms. Another optimization would be to first copy the file to a local disk